# Java Heap Space Error [Struts2 Json]

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I do have a Java web app(strust2) and it does use the `struts2-json` plugin, for handling `json` requests. Recently, I came down to an error `Java Heap Space` which is very strange.

This is in my `struts.xml`

```
      <action name="saveSigned"
        class="org.xxx.xxx.xxx.action.marriage.SaveSigned">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>

            <result type="json">  
            <param name="contentType">application/json</param>                  
            </result>           
        <param name="requiredAuthorities">F_ADD_MARRIAGE</param>

    </action>
```

The JSON data is generated and sent to this action `saveSigned`. This is the JSON data which is being sent:

> encodedBase64:"somebase64encodeddata",
>   uuId:"someUUID"

So I send only these 2 variables to be automatically handled by `struts2-json` plugin. Based on `uuId` I get some data from the `database`.. and this is where I get the error. I dont understand why it give me `jave heap error` bacause of `struts2-json`, when in the code I dont use it.

This is the pieace of code which throws this error:

```
marriage = xxxRegisterService.getMarriageUuId(getUuId());
```

The error itself

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>       at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
>       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
>       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
>       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
>       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
>       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:578)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:498)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:158)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:401)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:492)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:158)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:401)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:492)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:158)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:401)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
>       at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:492)

So, the `struts2-json` assigns only 1 simple text `uuId`.. and based on that `uuId` im getting some data from database and then assign it to the variable.

The strange part is that, everything works fine.. I can see all changes in the database, the application returns `success` but only after a minute it throws this error..

Comment: I look around `JSONWriter` there is a `protected string` method, which loops through characters, I think something goes wrong there! May be you can set some breakpoints there and see what is going there

Comment: where exactly? @AlirezaFattahi.

Comment: This struts class in `org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter` package